# How to learn image processing / computer vision in a practical way?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am new to the field of image processing / computer vision and I find it very hard to get my hands on the subject.
I read a lot about the basics/theory but I feel in no way able to use this knowledge in a practical way.

- Do you have any tips on how to translate my theoretical knowledge into practical knowledge?
- Are there any "cookbooks" for image processing that are not bound to a software/library? (I plan to use Halcon but only find resources for Photoshop or OpenCV.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Again, you're not giving any feedback to the answer you did get. Try responding in a comment to Temak. What DOESN'T that answer do for you?

Answer (score 2):

*Digital Image Processing*. Rafael C. Gonzalez, Richard E. Woods. - it is the classical book on Image Processing, that is not bound to any library.

To translate theoretical knowledge into practical knowledge you can start with the book *[Mastering OpenCV with Practical Computer Vision Projects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849517827)*, which can be downloaded [here](https://homepages.thm.de/~hg11237/Start/OpenCV/Mastering%20OpenCV%20with%20Practical%20Computer%20Vision%20Projects%20%5beBook%5d.pdf).